# Maximum number of nodes and edges on Boost Graph Library

Tags: boost, boost-graph

What is the maximum number of nodes and edges that a single graph structure can support with Boost Graph Library?

Answer (score 2):

The limits are defined by your platform only.

Depending on the memory efficiency of the chosen container selectors you can stuff all of your RAM.

In fact with distributed graph models ([Parallel Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/overview.html)) you can even surpass this limitation and raise to the limits of the machines in your cluster combined.

Of course, by then the limits might start to be dictated by the type chosen to represent the vertex index. Just make `int128_t` or so :)